# QTCreator under MSYS/Mingw - "Unable to create a debugging engine."

Tags: mingw, qt-creator, msys2

I cannot debug my C++ project in QTCreator.

I am running MSYS2/Mingw version:

`MINGW64_NT-10.0-19044 version 3.3.4-341.x86_64 (runneradmin@fv-az448-481) (gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC) )`

I am running QTCreator version:

`Qt Creator 7.0.0 based on Qt 6.2.4`

I am using the kit "Desktop Qt MinGW -w64 64bit (MSYS2)".

When I try to use "Start debugging of the startup project" I get the error:

`Unable to create a debugging engine.`

Here is a picture of my kits dialogue. [image]

I do have GDB installed, --version reports `GNU gdb (GDB) 11.1`.

As you can see, all the kits warn that no debugger is set up for them. However, the kit I've selected says that it is using the debugger "MinGW -w64 GDB (64bit)". I cannot change it, as the Manage option is greyed out.

How do I fix the debugging in QTCreator?

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple things I needed to do:

1: Install a newer GDB (mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb) (12.1).

2: Under Kits/Debuggers, create a new debugger option pointing to C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe. This may be not needed as it's identical to an auto-detected one, but I did so anyways.

3: Create a new kit which is mostly a copy of Desktop Qt MinGW -w64 64bit (MSYS2), and point it at the new debugger. (Can't modify automatically generated kits, only manually created kits)

4: Ensure when debugging to hit the "Start debugging of the startup project" option rather than the "Run" option. Unlike some other editors, a Debug build with breakpoints set will still skip past them if run normally and not using the Debug option.

After that, it works flawlessly.

Note: At some point, it apparently updated to QTCreator 8.0.1 as well.